# Terraform, using yamldeode() in my locals returns the wrong string

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating an eventGrid topic that loops over local variables and they import from a yaml file through yamldecode function.

```
locals {
  app_name  = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))["name"]
  version   = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))["version"]
  functions = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))["functions"]
}

resource "azurerm_eventgrid_topic" "function" {

  count = length(local.functions)

  name     = "topic-${local.functions[count.index]["name"]}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.core.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.core.location

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.functions
  ]
}
```

The returned error shows that the name is wrong, which makes me assume that it is somehow not getting the input from the locals variabls, what am i doing wrong ?

**error message:**

```
│ Error: invalid value for name (EventGrid topic name must be 3 - 50 characters long, contain only letters, numbers and hyphens.)
│ 
│   with azurerm_eventgrid_topic.function[2],
│   on main.tf line 66, in resource "azurerm_eventgrid_topic" "function":
│   66: resource "azurerm_eventgrid_topic" "function" {
```

This is how the yaml file looks like

[image]

any idea ?, appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it works, you can try it yourself by running below:

```
locals {
  app_name  = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))["name"]
  version   = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))["version"]
  functions   = yamldecode(file("config.yaml"))["functions"]
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  count = length(local.functions)

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo topic-${local.functions[count.index]["name"]} >> test.out"
  }
  triggers = {
  build_number = timestamp()
}
}

output "null" {
  value = null_resource.test
}
```

So the issue is with the event grid topic name. I looked at Microsoft doc and there are limitations on topic names. It cannot have underscores it can have hyphens. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/troubleshoot-errors and I noticed you are using underscores in the name.